# Is it possible to connect a router and a switch using fiber-optic cable in Packet Tracer?

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

Second question: Is there a way to connect a router and a switch using fiber-optic cable?

I am trying to connect a switch that has multiple servers connected to it to a router. The switch that I have used already have a GigabitEthernet interface but I cannot connect it to the router.

Sorry I am just a beginner. Suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: What difference does fiber vs copper make in Packet Tracer? Link is link.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Some devices in packet tracer have native optical interfaces and on some others you can add O.F. modules.

For each device, if you double-click on it and go on the `physical` tab, it will show you the available modules on the left side and the slot to put those modules in the upper central window.

[image]

The example below has a server connected with copper to the switch, which is in turn connected to two routers with fibers.

Also, as you can see, in the link selection, the orange one is for fibber. (but the links appear red once set)

[image]

However in packet tracer you can as well connect everything with copper, it will not change much your experience.